# Selenium IDE - Dynamic ID and Value

Tags: selenium, dynamic, ide

i have a problem with my dynamic id entries.

last name id changing like: last_name_12  or last_name_112 for example

I can find the dynamic field with:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'last_name_')]
```

my problem is, that if i find that ID and type a value and then go to another field the value in that field is deleted/vanished.

Can't seems to find a solution.

Thx you in Advance

Comment: Can you explain the value deletion in little more detail or better put up some html source and code.

Comment: my selenium ide:    if i run my script                                                                 type  //input[contains(@id, 'last_name_')]  mylastname                                             if i  now switch for example to                                                   //input[contains(@id, 'first_name_')] myfirstname                                                     the value i added "mylastname" is gone... it only shows it aslong i am in that field....    but it is working if i do it with my mouse

Comment: My apologies I did not check properly that this is related to Selenium IDE which I got no experience. But I still would suggest you add the relevant HTML source to your question

Comment: @mytrasher, you mean to say that, what ever values you are entering to Lastname text box is clearing off after you switch to next textbox. Am i right?

Comment: @Siva YES you are right!

Comment: @mytrasher, i guess you would have already tried, but still want to confirm, did you try the same manually, exactly with the same data that you tried with code? If not can you please try it? Also can you please share the HTML of the page link to see from my end

Comment: @Siva if i do it manually it is working... i cant get the code i think cause i am doing it for the firm i am doing internship

Comment: @mytrasher, okay, i will post if i get to know any thing regarding the solution.

Comment: @Siva thx you very much... its like the first time that something like that happening to me, that i just cant understand why it is clearing

Comment: @mytrasher, since you are saying it is ide did you try recording and playing it back by handling the dynamic values?

Comment: @mytrasher, what is the command you are using to enter values to the textbox? browser version as well please?

Comment: @Siva i wrote already   :D      it was       type //input[contains(@id, 'last_name_')] mylastname

Comment: @mytrasher, sorry for too many questions, im trying to find the cause and possible solutions. Can you try using `sendKeys` instead of `type`

Comment: @Siva SendKeys seems to WORK!!  but now its an other problem.... if i do sendkeys for example "hello"  the next time i do the same it will write "namename"  it will not delete the first one...

Comment: @mytrasher, in webdriver we have `.Clear()`, in IDE we dont have any such method, simple work around i would suggest is use `type` first and give value as blank, then your next command as `SendKeys` with value as you want it there

Comment: @Siva  the type command it not helping cause after i try type and after i leave the field... the original values i did with sendkeys are again on the field

Comment: @mytrasher, 'm not able to add the image via comment so i have added the image in answer, i guess it should work as it is working fine in my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it this way? Below one will send blank value to text box and then your desired values

[image]

Comment: its not working its just adding the values  Test123456Test123456

Comment: Its working thx you!!  it wasnt working with //input[contains(@id, 'fi-first_name_')]    but with name= firstname it was

Comment: I don't understand, its working perfectly well in one of my sample applications, are you sure you have your IDE commands as i have specified in the image for Type command, i just passed target and value as nothing

Comment: If every thing is good feel free to accept the answer, so that that would be ready made solution to other users who are looking for it

Comment: thx you very much for your help, i hope i wont get any problems :D    how do i accept anwers? cant seems to find it here

Comment: If you have any problems do drop a comment and unanswer the question in case you feel the answer is not giving you the solution fro your question. To accept the answer, please click on the tick mark below the down vote button.

Comment: i have habve the tick button there... only favorite Star mark

Comment: I mean in the my answer section, you could see Up/Down buttons next to my answer, below which you will have the tick mark.